# Dirac Delta applied to the gradient of a function

Tags: differentiation, mathematics, dirac-delta-distributions

The supplementary section of a paper I am reading uses the "substitution" property of the Dirac delta function :
$$\mathbf{v}\left(\mathbf{x}_j\right)\delta\left(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}_j\right)=\mathbf{v}\left(\mathbf{x}\right)\delta\left(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}_j\right)$$

I've never encountered this before.

1. How does one arrive at this expression?
2. Are there constraints on the what kind of parameters $x$ and $x_j$ need to be?
3. What if I have $(\nabla_j v(x_j)) \delta(x-x_j)$, where $\nabla_j$ is the derivative at  $j$? (It is a local coordinate system)

Here $x = x_j + \epsilon$.

Comment: Note that $v(x)\delta(x - x_j)$ is zero except at $x = x_j$ where $v(x)$ = $v(x_j)$.

Comment: Please ask only one question per post. If you want to ask about delta functions and gradients, don’t make that question #3.

Comment: Would [math.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function

Answer (score 1):

> The supplementary section of a paper I am reading uses the "substitution" property of the Dirac delta function :
> $$\mathbf{v}\left(\mathbf{x}_j\right)\delta\left(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}_j\right)=\mathbf{v}\left(\mathbf{x}\right)\delta\left(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}_j\right)$$
>
> 1. How does one arrive at this expression?

Remember that a Dirac delta function, despite the name, is not really a function; it is a functional.

What this means is that you can sometimes treat it like a function in formal manipulations, but it does not entirely make sense anywhere other than under the integral sign.

So, for example, it makes sense to say that:
$$
\int dx \underbrace{f(x)\delta(x-x_0)}_{integrand\;one} = f(x_0)\;.\tag{1}
$$
where the underbrace denotes the integrand.

Therefore, since
$$
\int dx \delta(x-x_0) = 1\tag{A}
$$
we also have:
$$
\int dx \underbrace{f(x_0)\delta(x-x_0)}_{integrand\;two} 
= f(x_0)\int dx \delta(x-x_0) 
=f(x_0)\;,\tag{2}
$$
which motivates the formal, but not entirely sensical, suggestion that integrand one in Eq. (1) is "equal to" integrand two in Eq. (2):
$$
f(x_0)\delta(x-x_0) \stackrel{"ish"}{=} f(x)\delta(x-x_0)\;.
$$

Or, removing the "ish" and taking the above equality for real we have:
$$
f(x_0)\delta(x-x_0) = f(x)\delta(x-x_0)\;,
$$
which can also be motivated by the pseudo-definition of a Dirac delta function as a "function" that is "zero everywhere except at the point where its argument is zero." The problem with this pseudo-definition is that a function that is zero everywhere except at a single point must integrate to zero, not to one, in contradiction to Eq. (A).

---

There are [other workable definitions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2833912/reference-for-dirac-delta-function-as-gaussian) as well.

---

> What if I have $(\nabla_j v(x_j)) \delta(x-x_j)$, where $\nabla_j$ is the derivative at  $j$?

This changes nothing, since the derivative of a function is another function.

For example, if I have a function
$g(x)$ then just  call its derivative
$f(x) = \frac{dg}{dx}$
and everything works the same:
$$
\int dx \frac{dg}{dx}\delta (x-x_0) = \int dx f(x)\delta(x-x_0) = f(x_0) = \left.\frac{dg}{dx}\right|_{x=x_0}
$$